# How to retrieve corresponding value of a filed with MAX on other fields in MySQL 4.0.x

Tags: mysql, sql

*To start with, I am using MySQL 4.0.27 and need solution for this
   version only.*

I am using MAX() in SELECT statement with other fields and need to retrieve the value of other fields which is corresponding to the value of MAX field.

Assume below data from table *Orders*:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Product    |      CategoryID     |   Date      |    OrderBy
--------------------------------------------------------------
TV         |     1               |  2011-11-27 |   John
Pen        |     1               |  2011-11-29 |   David
Mouse      |     2               |  2011-11-30 |   Mike
Printer    |     1               |  2011-10-19 |   Rozi
HDD        |     2               |  2011-11-02 |   Peter
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

My requirement is to retrieve count of orders in each category with name of individuals with recent Order, which means I need following result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CategoryID     |    OrderBy       |      Order_Count      |    Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             |    John          |      3                |    2011-11-29
2             |    Peter         |      2                |    2011-11-30
```

If I use below SQL:

```
SELECT CategoryID, OrderBy, COUNT(OrderID) AS Order_count, MAX(Date)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CategoryID
```

I am not getting desired result. I am getting some other name in OrderBy instead of the same name which is falling against extracted date.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this in MySQL 4.0.x where we have limitation of not using inner query or functions like GROUP_CONCAT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure, for category 1, wouldn't the name be David?? And for category 2, wouldn't it be Mike? They are the ones with the most recent date!

Comment: BTW, John is neither the most recent nor the oldest... Why do you expect John there anyway?

Comment: My apologies; you are correct, the result should have David for Cat 1 and Mile for Cat 2; but I am not getting this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CategoryID, OrderBy, COUNT(OrderID) AS Order_count, Date
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CategoryID
ORDER BY Date Desc
```

- assuming you want the OrderBy value corresponding to the maximum date.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it a great help to check in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) (although, despite what it says there, if the value to find the MAX for is not indexed, then this is more efficient than a sub-select)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT a.CategoryID, b.OrderBy, COUNT(DISTINCT a.id), MAX(a.Date) 
FROM Orders a 
INNER JOIN Orders b ON a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID 
GROUP BY a.CategoryID 
ORDER BY a.Date DESC,b.Date ASC
```